# Is there a max number of parallel Bolts-Android Tasks?

Tags: android, bolts-framework

I'm using the `BoltsFramework` (`Parse`) in an android `Application`. Let's say I want to launch in background several Parallel Tasks (so several Threads). Is there a limit to avoid to use too much Threads? Or can we put in a queue if the tasks are too many? I would like to avoid call the tasks in series.
The use case should be something like launch several task in parallel (huge number) and when All are completed do something….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bolts-Android uses a thread pool with a queue behind the scenes, so you don't have to worry about managing it yourself. If you want to see how it's implemented, you can see `BoltsExecutors.java` and `AndroidExecutors.java`.

In a JVM environment, it'll use the default `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` which has a limit of `Integer.MAX_INT` simultaneous parallel threads and a synchronous queue when it runs out of threads.

In an Android environment, it uses a custom pool size that sizes itself depending on how many cores your CPU has and has a synchronous queue when it runs out of threads as well.

You can also pass in your own `Executor` in several methods to manage the thread pool yourself.

https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/blob/master/bolts-tasks/src/main/java/bolts/BoltsExecutors.java

https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/blob/master/bolts-tasks/src/main/java/bolts/AndroidExecutors.java